# How do you get Ether Shield in Final Fantasy: Mystic Quest?

Tags: final-fantasy-mystic-quest

According to equipment list in [FF:MQ Walkthrough](http://www.neoseeker.com/resourcelink.html?rlid=139446&rid=129688), there are 4 shields in the game: Steel (found in Bone Dungeon), Venus (in Focus Tower), Ether and Aegis (Focus Tower / Doom Castle).

Ether shield is equipped by one of the companion NPCs (Phoebe), but is there any location to pick it up to equip Benjamin (your hero character)?

I tried pretty much all FAQs from [here](http://www.neoseeker.com/Games/Products/SNES/final_fantasy_mystic_quest/faqs.html), none has any location for it.

Comment: Someone with enough rep, please add "final-fantasy" and "final-fantasy-mq" tags

Comment: Only a game tag is really needed; a final-fantasy tag would be for the original final fantasy game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Ether Shield cannot be found in the game outside of the points when it is equipped to Phoebe. It is identical in fashion to the body armors that all four companions have that likewise cannot be found.

All of Benjamin's equipment comes as a set of three, which is also how it is rendered in the equipment screen. There isn't room for a fourth shield.

I'd imagine that the placement of the shield in both the Shield section and in the Other Character Armor section is just an odd choice from the writer of that particular guide.